# Google Android first application tutorial appears to be out of date

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to follow [Google's Android tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity) to create my first application, but either I'm looking in the wrong place or the tutorial is wrong/out of date for the latest version of Android Studio.

On the page I linked above, to add an onClick handler in the Design view of Studio, it contains the following instruction:

[image]

However, in the Attributes window, there is no onClick item. I could only add the onClick handler by editing the xml in text mode. Here's what my screen looks like when I have the button selected:

[image]

However, **after** I add the onclick event to the xml file, it does appear in the Attributes window.

Is the tutorial wrong, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version android you used, but in Android Studio Chipmunk, you can see **onclick** property at **Common Atttributes**

[image]

If you don't see **Common Attributes**, please check icon setting below **Design** button
[image]

Comment: I am using the very latest version of Android Studio: Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8815526, built on July 11, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.4
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 10
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin (212-1.7.10-release-333-AS5457.46)

I added a new button, and  can see the Common Attributes panel, but there is no `onClick` item.